# Pycharm Question :I s there anyway that i can go back after searching for definition etc by using CTRL+LEFT CLICK?

Tags: python, pycharm, shortcut

I'm now very excited to use pycharm.
It has very interesting debugging skills and helps me a lot.
I use CTRL+Left Click to search for definitions of functions and classes but i can't find way to go back by shortcuts. is there anyway going back???

Comment: ctr+tab will bring you back to where you were

Comment: thanks a lot !! that's very useful answer.

Comment: OR else you can just shut code window by ctrl+f4!